# Wouldn't it be possible to smoothly scroll the chart to the left in Apache ECharts dynamic data samples?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am trying to decorate a chart using Apache ECharts dynamic data.
(https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dynamic-data)

I want the updated data to flow naturally, not simply delete and add (shift and push).

Similar plugins exist for chart.js.
(chartjs-plugin-streaming)

Is there any way to get the same result in ECharts?

I'm still in the technical review phase, only testing through the demo site. I would like to see if the technology is feasible and if possible, I would like to obtain a sample.